# My NGINX secure link keep getting 403 and can't find useful log neither in error.log nor access.log

Tags: typescript, nginx

Below is my nginx.conf setting. I have tried to add some headers for debugging.

```
location /secureMedia {
    root html/secureMedia;
    
    secure_link $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
    secure_link_md5 "$secure_link_expires$uri$remote_addr secret";
    
    add_header debugging1 "$arg_md5" always;
    add_header debugging2 "$secure_link_expires$uri$remote_addr secret"  always;
    add_header help-debug "X$secure_link"  always;
    
    if ($secure_link = "") { 
        return 403; 
        }
        
    if ($secure_link = "0") { 
        return 410; 
        }
}
```

My typescript code.

```
import * as CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

 generateSecureLinkSvc(url) {
    let secret = "secret";
    let domain = "http://localhost:8080";
    let uriPath = "/upload/image/test.jpg";
    let expiration = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600;
    let userIp = "127.0.0.1";

    let fMd5 = `${expiration}${uriPath}${userIp} ${secret}`;
    let md = CryptoJS.MD5(fMd5);
    md = md.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    md = md.replace(/=/g, "").replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_");


    return domain + uriPath + `?md5=${md}&expires=${expiration}`;
 }
```

My access.log
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2023:13:47:08 +0800] "GET /secureMedia/upload/image/test.jpg?md5=ft-HAimVS6OBsZ20iUsvbg&expires=1690094667 HTTP/1.1" 403 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

I need to restrict the media URL from unauthenticated user. Therefore, link expiration is required. I have referred to some sources but still can't figure out what is going wrong.

Sources:
https://github.com/veryacademy/yt-nginx-mastery-series
https://rahul-juneja3.medium.com/how-to-create-secure-download-link-urls-via-nginx-5578a0db5913